# how to load NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults in AppDelegate in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, appdelegate

i don't understand how to use `NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults` correctly. I have `GameOver.m` file, were score is checked if its high score, and if it is it gets saved like this :

```
if(score > highScore){
  highScore =score;
  bestScore = highScore;

  NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [prefs setInteger:bestScore forKey:@"bestScore"];
  [prefs synchronize];
}
```

To load High score i use:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger theHighScore =[prefs integerForKey:@"bestScore"];
```

it works, but after app is closed and reopen highscore is gone, I read, that loading process needs to be in AppDelegate file in `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`, how can i do that?

**Edit**
**GameScene.m**

```
-(void)Scoring {
  NSUserDefaults *scoreprefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [scoreprefs setInteger:score forKey:@"score"];
}
```

**GameScene.m**

```
#import "GameScene.h"
@implementation GameOver
NSInteger score;
NSInteger highScore;
NSInteger bestScore;

- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size playerLose:(BOOL)isLose {
  self = [super initWithSize:size];
  if (self) {
    NSUserDefaults *scoreprefs =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger score = [scoreprefs integerForKey:@"score"];

    SKLabelNode *scorelabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Menlo-Bold"];
    scorelabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)score];
    // then i define position/fontsize for scoreLabel
    [self addChild:scorelabel];

    if(score > highScore){
      highScore =score;
      bestScore = highScore;

      NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      [prefs setInteger:bestScore forKey:@"bestScore"];
      [prefs synchronize];
    }

    NSUserDefaults *prefs =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger theHighScore =[prefs integerForKey:@"bestScore"];
    SKLabelNode *highscorelabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Menlo-Bold"];
    highscorelabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)theHighScore];
    //define position/fontsize for highscorelabel
  }
  return self;
}
```

And thats it, it.

Comment: Please check you are not overwriting key @"bestScore" anywhere.

Comment: are your used this word in any where in your app [removeobjectforkey:@"bestScore"];

Comment: Check whether you have remove this key anywhere in project.

Comment: you will be setting some nil value in AppDelegate DidFinishLaunching method

Comment: Where is the `bestScore` variable initialized?

Comment: @user345095 only place were besides this were i use bestscore is to put it on screen in `highscorelabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)theHighScore];` and thats all.

Comment: @trojanfoe under `@implementation GameOver   NSInteger bestScore;`

Comment: @jogshardik this is only place were i use it

Comment: @artG [prefs setInteger:bestScore forKey:@"bestScore"]; at this point, does best score has correct values? because your code looks fine here.

Comment: @artG And it's initialized to the current value stored in `NSUserDefaults`?  Please show all the relevant code.

Comment: @user345095 yes,it have, as i sad only problem is wen i close app and reopen it, then  bestScore is lost

Comment: @trojanfoe i just added all code were `NSUserDefaults` shows up in my code

Comment: So there are paths where `bestScore` isn't initialized.  Also why are they global instead of being properties of instance variables?

Comment: @trojanfoe becausein beggining i didn't know were i use them, thats why they're  global

Comment: That's not a good enough reason.  Please fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@interface GameOver ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger score;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger highScore;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger bestScore;
@end

@implementation GameOver
@synthesize score,bestScore,highScore;

- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size playerLose:(BOOL)isLose {
    NSUserDefaults *scoreprefs =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        if (self) {

            score = [scoreprefs integerForKey:@"score"];
            highScore = [scoreprefs integerForKey:@"bestScore"];

            SKLabelNode *scorelabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Menlo-Bold"];
            scorelabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)score];
            // then i define position/fontsize for scoreLabel
            [self addChild:scorelabel];

            if(score > highScore){
                highScore =score;
                bestScore = highScore;

                [scoreprefs setInteger:bestScore forKey:@"bestScore"];
                [scoreprefs synchronize];
            }

            SKLabelNode *highscorelabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Menlo-Bold"];
            highscorelabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)highScore];
            //define position/fontsize for highscorelabel
        }

    }
        return self;
}
```

Problem was that you not initialised your HighScore , and checking

`score(assume 5242)>highScore(nil)`

were always true

EDITED

Comment: :(
Seems i'm too late

Comment: @Mr.Fingers thank you, I try your code and it works. My programming thinking is no good. I have much to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You are not fetching the data for hi-score. So the following condition holds good every time since the `highScore` variable will be 0. At this stage, the `bestScore` is overwritten by current score even when the `bestScore` is greater than the `score`

```
if(score > highScore){ //Will be true always. Not proper condition.
  highScore =score;
  bestScore = highScore;

  NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [prefs setInteger:bestScore forKey:@"bestScore"];
  [prefs synchronize];
}
```

Comment: NSUSerDefaults, after synchronize, keeps the data as long as app is not deleted.

Comment: My bad. I have edited the answer for the question asked. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Also, he should not use 65535 variables just for `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` and not reuse the first one. I feel sorry for those iOS devices that needs to run such dirty codes. :x